# Flatten the JSON which has comma's in the input value

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am facing a problem, transforming a very complex JSON which has commas in the input values. I need to separate the comma separated values into different records using jolt transformation. Input and output detail is given below.

**Input** :

```json
{
  "DeptID": "339283",
  "EmpID": "280908,280909",
  "EmpCode": "123,31424",
  "Manager":"James,Thiyags"
}
```

**Output Expected** :

```json
[
  {
    "DeptID": "339283",
    "EmpID": "280908",
    "EmpCode": "123",
    "Manager":"James"
  },
  {
    "DeptID": "339283",
    "EmpID": "280909",
    "EmpCode": "31424",
    "Manager":"Thiyags"
  }
]
```

Pls help Can anyone who is a jolt expert, help me get the desired output. I think i m stuck in the last step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **split** by commas within the **modify** transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "EmpID": "=split(',',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  { // loop through the "EmpID" array
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "EmpID": {
        "*": { // indexes of the array
          "@": "[#2].&2", // &2 replicates the key name "EmpID"
          "@2,DeptID": "[#2].DeptID"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Edit** : *You can use the following spec based on your last edit*

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Emp*": "=split(',',@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Emp*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[#2].&2",
          "@2,DeptID": "[#2].DeptID"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your continued support

Comment: What if i hv more one that one columns with comma separated like EmpId, EmpName?

Comment: @ThiyagarajNarayanan Need to see your assumption as a concrete example

Comment: Updated the question with the latest input json @barbaros

Comment: I have added one more column to the Input JSON with a different column name @barbaros